# OpenCV Error ( 'src_type' is 16 (CV_8UC3) ) While Doing THRESH_OTSU

Tags: python

My Code is Giving Error at:

```
region = cv2.threshold(region, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

At the previous questions, people were saying "You should use uint8 or uint16 in your image." but I already did. Here is the code:

```
  region = image[ int(roi[0]):int(roi[2]), int(roi[1]):int(roi[3])]

  region = region.astype("uint8")
  print(region)
  region = cv2.threshold(region, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
  region = cv2.medianBlur(region, 3)
```

Here is how region look like:

```
[[[127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  ...
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]]

 [[127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  ...
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]]

 [[127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  ...
  [ 25  26  82]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]]

 ...

 [[127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  ...
  [  0   4  49]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]]

 [[127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  ...
  [  0   5  45]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]]

 [[127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  ...
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]
  [127 255   0]]]
```

And here is the error:

```
     48       region = region.astype("uint8")
     49       print(region)
---> 50       region = cv2.threshold(region, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
     51       region = cv2.medianBlur(region, 3)
     52 

error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-req-build-fvfwe_ss/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1557: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'double cv::threshold(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, double, double, int)'
> THRESH_OTSU mode:
>     'src_type == CV_8UC1 || src_type == CV_16UC1'
> where
>     'src_type' is 16 (CV_8UC3)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the doc of `cv2.thershold` :

> The first argument is the source image, which should be a grayscale
> image

Source:
[offical doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57)

And: [official tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

So the answer to your problem is simply convert to grayscale, for example with:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```